# what privillege should I give to the kubernetes nfs mount path

Tags: kubernetes

when I start the postgresql in kubernetes cluster, the log look like this:

```
postgresql 07:00:48.68 
postgresql 07:00:48.68 Welcome to the Bitnami postgresql container
postgresql 07:00:48.68 Subscribe to project updates by watching https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-postgresql
postgresql 07:00:48.68 Submit issues and feature requests at https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-postgresql/issues
postgresql 07:00:48.68 
postgresql 07:00:48.70 INFO  ==> ** Starting PostgreSQL setup **
postgresql 07:00:48.72 INFO  ==> Validating settings in POSTGRESQL_* env vars..
postgresql 07:00:48.72 INFO  ==> Loading custom pre-init scripts...
postgresql 07:00:48.73 INFO  ==> Initializing PostgreSQL database...
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/bitnami/postgresql/data’: Permission denied
```

so what permission should I give to the minimal `/bitnami/postgresql/data` folder? and why should I give this permission?